# How to keep a singleton when closing a Sprite Kit game?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I use a singleton that saves the changes in my game and works well. How can I keep a singleton when closing the game?  Should I use `NSCoder`?

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class War: SKScene {

    static var sharedWar = War(size: CGSize(width: 2048, height: 1536))
    ...

}
```

Comment: I suggest to use [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults)

Comment: use Firebase or another baas

Comment: why is sharedWar a singleton btw?  Is there something outside of spritekit that needs to know what it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to save the entire scene,  `SKScene` already conforms to `NSCoding` it is a matter of saving it to a file, and loading it.  Now if you need to save an entire object,  I would not recommend using `NSUserDefault`, use the `documentDirectory` instead.

Keep in mind, you will need to override `init?(coder:)` and `encode(with: NSCoder)` to save any new variables attached to your GameScene.

```
// Get documents directory
if let docs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first {

    // Append your file name to the directory path
    let path = (docs as NSString).appendingPathComponent("filename")

    // Archive your object to a file at that path
    NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(yourObject, toFile: path)
}
```

Loading:

```
// Get documents directory
if let docs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first {

    // Append your file name to the directory path
    let path = (docs as NSString).appendingPathComponent("filename")

    // Unarchive your object from the file
    let yourObject = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: path) as? Book

    // do whatever with yourObject
}
```

Source:[How to use persist & retrieve an NSCoding compliant object to app Document directory in Swift 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38666015/how-to-use-persist-retrieve-an-nscoding-compliant-object-to-app-document-direc)

Comment: Thank you! I try to understand)

Comment: how to call methods Save and Load?

Comment: Look at the source I provided

Comment: I dont know what you are trying to do,  I gave you the methods on how to save and load.  You would create your own functions  out of the code I gave you, and use it when you need to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Save in UserDefaults is the best and easy way

To save:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject(War.size.width forKey: "width")
defaults.setObject(War.size.height, forKey: "height")
```

To load:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if let width = defaults.floatForKey("width"),
   let height = defaults.floatForKey("height")  {

   print(CGSizeMake(width: width, height: height)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! NSUserDefaults could save the whole scene?

Comment: I need to save the current "static var sharedWar"